# How does Serialize and De-serialize work internally?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a lot of legacy code where `json` is parsed manually by using a for loop. This takes `O(n)` time in general. I know `json.net` would be better in terms of `time` and `space` but gaining an insight about how it works, would help me make an informed decision whether its worth the effort to actually go ahead and invest the time and man power to move everything to json.net.

Comment: You're expecting an algorithm that is faster than a single iteration through the data?

Comment: What are you hoping to get out of this question?  Anyone can gain insight about how JSON.NET works, simply by looking at the source code: http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65597

Comment: I guess he is looking for inside working

Comment: *"How does this work internally"* is not the same as *"should I use it"*.

Comment: "How does this work internally" helps me decide whether I should use it or not.

Comment: I tried looking at the code and was finding it hard to decide. Is it wrong to ask for an opinion from people who know more than yourself?

Comment: @AbhishekIyer - It's not *wrong* to ask for an opinion, but SO is probably not the correct forum for a discussion about a library. As stated in the FAQ "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." You may fair better on one of the other stackexcahnge sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To paraphrase your question into a more general one, lets assume you were looking for advice on which JSON serialization implementation to choose for various scenarios.

I'm aware of three obvious answers to this question:

- NewtonSoft JSON.NET

  - Provides an abundance of features and excellent performance
- ServiceStack.Text

  - Provides simplicity and blazing performance
- BCL JsonSerializer

  - Avoids the 3rd party library dependency, but is significantly slower

If you don't care about the 3rd party library dependency, go for the first option as it will give you performance and functionality. If you don't need a ton of features, evaluate whether ServiceStack.Text does what you need it to (if unsure, go with JSON.NET). In any other case, stick with what you have.

Also, don't spend time making your code faster by replacing your JSON code before you know that this particular area is a performance bottleneck (or otherwise warrants replacement, e.g. because it's a maintenance problem). If you are considering replacing code to gain performance, isolate a few methods to profile and benchmark your current code against similar scenarios using the alternate implementation or library, in order to avoid making a decision based on assumptions.

Last, knowing how it works internally should not be a factor in your decision process unless you specifically are planning to be able to modify the source of it (or otherwise need to be able to understand it).